# Windows 10 App Tiles and Icons

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Hello Fellow Developers...

After 2 months, I am excited to reach the final phase of my first Universal App for Windows 10. It's a game I built for my son actually.

BUT....

The Tiles and Icons section is becoming a painful process, so many different icons I can't remain focus! My app is for all devices, hence the complication.

Please, can anyone point me in the right direction? This is all that my [FIRST] app needs to submit for certification...

[EDIT]
I didn't actually asked the question correctly. What I meant to ask is, how can I generate all the needed images for the icons/tiles for my app? I know Photoshop Very well and used an action I found, but it doesn't create all of them.

Thanks a Mill.
Matias

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to know how can I generate all the images required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for Visual Studio: [UWP TileGenerator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenchauhan.UWPTileGenerator)

You have also this tool for Photoshop: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=760394. Link found on [design guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design-downloads/index).

Finally, this website allows to generate icons for several kind of application including UWP applications: http://cthedot.de/icongen

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I tried the extension though but it freezes my VS ... I left it for 15 min... does it take longer than that? I will download and try PS tool tomorrow and give feedback. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's strange. I also found this web site which generates all the images quickly: http://cthedot.de/icongen/ . Select UWP Windows 10 Universal App and UWP Windows 10 Universal App for store.

Comment: Alright Arnaud, I did use the Photoshop Actions, it did all the images for me, I used the correct PSD with the correct action. However, I found that the Badge Logo was not generated, is this critical for submission?

EDIT- I tried the website, and the website did generated the badge logo, was easy... I will try now and load it to the app and give feedback.

Comment: Fantastic! Worked like a bomb.... One more question though... the images generated from the website I said they must be transparent, which they are... all my other images are transparent too (generated from the PS Actions) but the Badge Logos don't have the background colors, is that normal? all my other assets load the background color at the root of the All Image assets place.

Comment: Yes, Badge logos should be transparent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated Arnaud for your help.